# python public ip with sockets (err:cannot assign requested addr)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ip, ip-address

After allowing my raspberry pi to access port 9999 of my router `socketname.bind(96.231.140.202,9999)` in python gives me a cannot assign error  

To port forward I used:
myfiosgateway.com/#/firewall/portforward (the same method 

worked fo my apache server) and I have verified that 96.231.140.202 is my pub ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind to your public IP. Your router is doing that. You instead want to bind to your private IP and port forward traffic destined to 9999 to your bound IP on your pi, this address will fall into the rfc compliant private IP ranges, so it will most likely be something like 192.168.1.12 or something similar.

For example:

```
socketname.bind(0.0.0.0,9999) #the use of 0.0.0.0 will automatically find your available interface on that raspberry pi.
```

If you let me know exactly what socket library youa re using I can craft the exact code.