# Python bind public ip to connect without same network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, ipv6

I want to bind public ip to connect socket without same network. How should I do it?

I tried:

```
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Set the socket
    server.bind(("public_ip", 12345))
```

And I got an error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

**why is not it working? And am I on the right path to receive messages from a client that is not on the same network?**

Comment: If it is a public IP, why you didn't show it (with the true port number, too)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python cannot bind my external/public ip address using socket, gives error But when using local ip address the error doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509626/), [Using public IP address in sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198388), [python public ip with sockets (err:cannot assign requested addr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779355).

Comment: You can only bind to addresses that are configured on your own host.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried to understand, but I was not so successful. Do you have any code to show me?

Comment: @ZivSion: There is no code to show. You simply can only bind to an IP at your local machine - and your public IP on the internet is the external IP of your router and not an IP you have on your local machine.